# Loop through checkboxes values in a form

Tags: angular, forms

So I have this FormGroup:

```
userExtraAct:FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    pool: "",
    kino: "",
    resturant: ""
  })
```

Looks like this in the tamplate:

```
<section class="extraAct" formGroupName="extraAct">
                <h4>Kan vi friste med ekstraaktiviteter?</h4>
                <p><mat-checkbox formControlName="pool">Badebasseng</mat-checkbox></p>
                <p><mat-checkbox formControlName="kino">Kino</mat-checkbox></p>
                <p><mat-checkbox formControlName="resturant">Resturant</mat-checkbox></p>
</section>
```

What I want to to is go through each of the checkboxes and see if they're checked or not. I know I can check each element individually like this:

```
let extraAct:FormArray = this.hotelRegUser.get("extraAct") as FormArray
    if (this.userExtraAct.controls["kino"].value == true){
      console.log("Boom")
    }
```

But that isn't particularly efficient if I add more and more checkboxes. I was thinking about maybe using the forEach in some way, but couldn't make it work.
A log like this only gives undefined:

```
console.log(extraAct.controls[0])
```

[This is what it looks like in the console when i log extraAct.controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGtyW.png)

Comment: Object.values(this.userExtraAct.controls).forEach(({value}) => console.log(value)) ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try using your checkboxes as a FormArray
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: Link-only answers may become outdated. We would ask that you include the essential parts in this answer and only provide the link for further reference, (not the complete solution).